# How do I loop through the elements of a list as a part of dplyr's filter capability and eventually print variance in R?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, var

I have a dataframe called diamondsData that I would like to manipulate in such a was that allows me to calculate the the variance in carat size for each type of cut in R.

[image: I want to get the variance of carat size for each type of cut, such as Ideal, Premium, etc.]

I can easily do it manually as follows:

```
diamondsData %>% 
  filter(cut=="Fair") %>% 
  select(carat) %>% 
  var()
```

I can change "Fair in filter(cut=="Fair") to Ideal and so on, but I would like to automate this. I tried creating a list and looping through like :

```
y <- list("Ideal", "Premium", "Good", "Very Good", "Fair")

for(x in y){
  print(
    diamondsData %>% 
      filter(cut==x) %>% 
      select(carat) %>% 
      var()
  )
}
```

but this doesn't work. This resulted in:

[[image: The result of my loop attempt2]

I am working in R. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use group_by instead of looping:

```
diamondsData %>%
group_by(cut) %>%
select(carat) %>%
summarize(variability = var(carat))
```

And it should give you a dataframe containing the variance of carat within each cut.

Edited to replace `%>% var()` with `%>% summarise(....)`.

Comment: Thanks for that, but this gives me the variance of all the group combined. How do I seperate them? Its as if the group_by function doesnt work

Comment: When I did `diamonds %>% group_by(cut)  %>% select(carat)  %>% summarize(variability = var(carat)) ` on the built-in diamonds dataset it gave me a 5 x 2 tibble with a row for each cut, so they're already separate. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `var` expects a `vector` while `select` returns a `data.frame/tibble` as output (even when one column is selected).  We can use `pull` to get the column as `vector`

```
for(x in y){
  print(
   diamondsData %>% 
   filter(cut==x) %>% 
    pull(carat) %>% 
     var(., na.rm = TRUE)
 )
}
```

Comment: I get all NA values for this result, but it did separate the cuts. Do you think there might be an issue with my list?